# How to sort products by price ASC and place all no price products to the end? (Woocommerce)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, order, sort

I have such trouble, tried a lot of solutions, but nothing worked for me.

I need to show all 'no price' products in the end of catalog, when I am sorting products by price ASC in Woocommerce.

Comment: Can you show us one solution you've tried and maybe someone can help you move the no price products to the end? How are no price products stored in WooCommerce - missing some post meta attribute?

Comment: But please bear in mind that WooCommerce is technically off topic here as a third-party plugin, so you might do better asking in a WooCommerce forum. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

**Default WooCommerce Product Sorting:**

To enable the default WooCommerce product sorting, simply go to the WooCommerce Settings > Product Tab and set to sort by price (asc or desc).

Also, it is an off topic here as a third-party plugin. Please go to WooCommerce support for better suggesstions.